# Call Dialog Methods form a static Class in C#

Tags: c#, class, methods, dialog

I have to catch an event from a parent dialog that uses a method from a static class to update an array.

From this dialog I call a child dialog that shows the array in a list.

I know with a variable if the current dialog is the child or the parent dialog, but from the method in the static class how can I call the method inside the child dialog to update the list when I catch the event?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the instance of the dialog into the static method like below.  I would definitely revisit your architecture if you're having a static method call into your dialog's methods however.

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
   public static void SomeMethod(Form myDialog)
   {
      myDialog.SomeMethodOnTheDialog();
   }
}
```

Comment: i'll try to set a catch event in every dialog that call a method inside for call the method in the class, so when it come back from the class method, i can use local method in dialog with no problem.  But is possible to reset the catch for the parent dialog before open the child dialog? do i have to set it = null?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your static method to take an instance of the Dialog as a parameter:

```
public static void UpdateArray(Dialog instance)
{
     // Initialize what you need

     instance.DoSomething();
}
```

Then you would all it in your Event Handler like:

```
public void Dialog_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dialog dialog = (Dialog) sender;
    UpdateArray(dialog);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i think that if i set the catch in parent and child dialogs togheter, i don't have the right Dialog instance in the UpdateArray.. So the catch is for the first that i set, or random choose? i develope in netcf 3.5, the parent dialog is opened but hide, only the child dialog is shown..

Answer (score 0):

Inside the class for the child dialog, you have to create public methods that do what you need them to do.

Then, you just call those **public method from the static class**.

This is a mini-example where I called a public method (in my Main form) from a static class.  I think this is similar to what you are doing.

---

**Main Form Snippet**

```
public static void WriteToTextBox(string message)
{
    TextBox myLog = (TextBox)CITX12Parser.Main.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("txtLog", true).First();
    myLog.Text = message;
}
```

**Static class snippet**

```
public class LoggingUtils
{
    public static void TestLog(string msg)
    {
        Main.WriteToTextBox(msg + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```